# Trigger to create new event after insert/update creating dupes

Tags: trigger, event

I have a trigger that should create a new event after insert or after update of a custom object called Handoff, but only if a custom field (Status) of that new record = "Delivered"

The after insert portion works fine, but the after update portion seems to always create duplicate events (two, to be precise).

I can't quite seem to find where it's going wrong within the trigger... any ideas?

```
trigger CreateEventAfterHandoff on Handoff__c (after insert, after update) {

List<Event> lstNewEvents = new List<Event>();

for (Handoff__c eve : Trigger.new) {

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

        if (eve.Status__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(eve.Id).Status__c) { 

        // Field has been changed! 

            if (eve.Status__c == 'Delivered') {

                Event e         = new Event();

                e.Event_Type__c     = eve.Event_Type__c;
                e.Meeting_Type__c   = eve.Meeting_Type__c;
                e.StartDateTime     = eve.Meeting_Time_Start__c;
                e.EndDateTime       = eve.Meeting_Time_Stop__c;
                e.Subject           = eve.Name;
                e.WhoId             = eve.Lead__c;
                e.OwnerId           = eve.User__c;
                e.Handoff_ID__c     = eve.Id;

                lstNewEvents.add(e);

            }           

        }

    } else if (Trigger.isInsert) {

        if (eve.Status__c == 'Delivered') {

            Event e         = new Event();

            e.Event_Type__c     = eve.Event_Type__c;
            e.Meeting_Type__c   = eve.Meeting_Type__c;
            e.StartDateTime     = eve.Meeting_Time_Start__c;
            e.EndDateTime       = eve.Meeting_Time_Stop__c;
            e.Subject           = eve.Name;
            e.WhoId             = eve.Lead__c;
            e.OwnerId           = eve.User__c;
            e.Handoff_ID__c     = eve.Id;

            lstNewEvents.add(e);

        }

    }           

}

insert lstNewEvents;     

}
```

Comment: do you have a second trigger on `Handoff__c` that does an update on `Handoff__c` ?  If so, this trigger will get executed twice in the update use case. Also field update on workflow. Check your debug log to see what is happening in the transaction; Also see recipe: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers

Comment: There are workflows running with field updates that fire things again, so that must be the issue. I'm thinking the simplest way of correcting it would be to create a field that is ticked when the event is created, then the trigger checks that and if it's ticked, it doesn't do it again. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Unless the workflow field update is time-based, then use the technique in the recipe as it will 'persist' through all `handoff__c` triggers, including those fired via workflow field updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the cause is either

1. You have a second trigger somewhere else in your code base on
   `Handoff__c` that in turn does a DML update on itself  or
2. You have a field update on `Handoff__c` via a workflow that will cause the after update trigger to be reinvoked.

You can resolve either of these by using the controlling recursive triggers recipe as shown in the [SFDC doc here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/controlling-recursive-triggers) or [here in Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US). You may also be able to control it by tighter if statements to avoid creating the Events even if invoked twice.

This [SFSE post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/57639/2602) addresses workflows and updates of greater than 200 records

Lastly, examine your debug log to see where the after update trigger on Handoff__c gets reinvoked, this may provide additional insight